# Can someone help fix these various JavaScript errors?

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript code have much errors - any one can help me to make it work?

> Line 6: Missing semicolon.
>
> Line 11: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 11 and instead saw ';'.
>
> Line 11: Expected an identifier and instead saw '&'.
>
> Line 11: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression.
>
> Line 11: Missing semicolon.
>
> Line 16: Missing semicolon.

Code:

```
1 <script type='text/javascript'>
2 var isCtrl = false;
3 document.onkeyup=function(e)
4 {
5 if(e.which == 17)
6 isCtrl=false;
7 }
8 document.onkeydown=function(e)
9 {
10 if(e.which == 17)
11 isCtrl=true;
12 if((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 67) &amp;&amp; isCtrl == true)
13 {
14 // alert(&#8216;Keyboard shortcuts are cool!&#8217;);
15 return false;
16 }
17 }
18 var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;
19 if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);
20 function mischandler(){
21 return false;
22 }
23 function mousehandler(e){
24 var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
25 var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
26 if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
27 }
28 document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
29 document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
30 document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
31 </script>
```

Comment: what do you not understand? the errors are pretty straight forward

Comment: also why are you using html codes here `if((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 67) &amp;&amp; isCtrl == true)`

Comment: I don't know but this js wont Minify here
https://javascript-minifier.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue in this line:

```
if((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 67) &amp;&amp; isCtrl == true)
```

Fixed:

```
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e)
{
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=false;
}
document.onkeydown=function(e)
{
if(e.which == 17)
isCtrl=true;
if((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 67) && isCtrl == true)
{

return false;
}
}
var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;
if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);
function mischandler(){
return false;
}
function mousehandler(e){
var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
}
document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
```

Comment: tnks but that same "Piyush.kapoor" code & when I add to my page show me error "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference" when minify or not

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
var isCtrl = false;
 document.onkeyup=function(e)
{
if(e.which == 17) 
 isCtrl=false;
 }
 document.onkeydown=function(e)
 {
if(e.which == 17) {
 isCtrl=true;
}

 if((e.which == 85) || (e.which == 67) && isCtrl == true)
 {
 // alert(&#8216;Keyboard shortcuts are cool!&#8217;);
 return false;
 }
 }
 var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;
if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") {
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);
} 
function mischandler(){
 return false;
 }
 function mousehandler(e){
var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
 var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
 if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
 }
 document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
 document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
 document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
</script>
```

Errors should be fixed now. 
I have changed & ==> & and used {} for single line if statements

P.S. If you want to minify it remove the script tags

Comment: ty for help now I can minify it but when I add to my page show me error

"The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference"

when minify or not